# Low power toggle switch

Tags: power-supply, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, 555, low-power

I have used a 555 to toggle output on/off from a push button pulse and was wondering to use something similar to TTP223 due to its low consume once with 555 have more than 10mA in standby, anyway touch switch is not the best approuch for my app.

Any tip for a ic toggle switch to use with LM2596 with a pushbutton and very low energy in standby?

Comment: The LM2596 datasheet from TI appears to say worst case standby current (on/off) is 250 μA over its operating temperature range. 80 μA typical. That's actually a lot compared to what can be done with a toggle button and an MCU (PIC10LF320 has worst case 13 μA sleeping on watchdog and 800 nA typical.) An MCU will also give you debounce and other features you decide about, when and if you do want to change things up. Toolchain is the cost, though. Do you want a capacitive type switch, though? MSP430 can do much better, but is unnecessary here.

Comment: You can use a D-flip flop. Like 74HC74. You can connect the output (Q) of the flip-flop to the enable pin of the LM2596, controlling its on/off state. If you ever want to make a DPDT toggle switch PCB, you can follow this design:  https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/THREE_WAY_DPDT_TOGGLE_SWITCH_PCB_a7d13c71.html

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a CMOS version of the 555, according to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf) for the LMC555 the supply current is maximum 400 uA @ 12 V. The [TLC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf) has a higher maximum voltage rating (18 V vs. 15 V) and max supply current is up to 1 mA @ 15 V.

Comment: Just waiting for the part to make a pratical test, tks, nice tip

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason to use a 555-like as a toggle latch, when you can just use simple low-power logic to accomplish the same thing. For the most basic option, you can hook up a D-type flip flop like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Ed3z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output will toggle for every rising edge of the input. This can be implemented in a single [74LVC1G74](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G74.pdf) with a quiescent current of 4 μA maximum, or if a 3.3 V logic level is suitable, you can get 0.5 μA quiescent with a [74AUP1G74](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AUP1G74.pdf).

Comment: Debounce needed.

Comment: @periblepsis No mention of debouncing was made in the question, so I'm assuming we're just trying to replace a 555 being used as a flip-flop. The same debounce circuitry that's currently being used can then be used with this and you save the 555's excessive quiescent current.

Comment: I know it wasn't mentioned. But the OP is clearly considering a manual switch -- capacitive device suggested, but I think that leaves open the possibility of any toggle switch. So the issue likely arises in the scenario you mention. I can't even begin to count the number of times the uninitiated (in manual switches) have come to learn the lesson the hard way. And a DFF is the most sure way to have that lesson taught the hard way.